# cURL command won't work in python TCP shell script

Tags: python, curl, tcp

I was writing a TCP shell script to run some CMD commands on a server (laptop). I got some basic commands working like `ipconfig`  and `whoami` and got the output sent back to the client terminal.

when I tried to run this command: `curl https://media.wired.co.uk/photos/607d91994d40fbb952b6ad64/4:3/w_2664,h_1998,c_limit/wired-meme-nft-brian.jpg --output yo.jpg` it would show this on the server terminal:
[output of server terminal after running command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIugY.png)

I tried running this command manually on the server and it worked fine, anyone knows why is this happening?

Client Code:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
   s.connect((HOST, PORT))
   s.settimeout(1.0)  # waiting 1 second for data to be sent back before continuing from s.recv

while True:
    command = input("Enter command:\n")
    s.sendall(command.encode())

    try:
        data = s.recv(2048)  # Waiting for data to be sent back
    except socket.error:  # Checking if there is data
        print("NO DATA")
    else:
        print(data.decode())  # Decode the data
```

Server Code:

```
import socket
import os

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
PORT = 5000
sock.bind(('', PORT))
sock.listen(5)
try:
    while True:
        newSocket, address = sock.accept()
        print("Connected from", address)

        while True:
            receivedData = newSocket.recv(2048)
            receivedData = receivedData.decode()
            print(str(receivedData))
            output = os.popen(receivedData).read()
            output = str(output)
            newSocket.sendall(output.encode())
        newSocket.close()
        print("Disconnected from", address)
finally:
    sock.close()
```

Comment: it worked fine on the server aswell? It performed the curl and saved the image to yo.jpg on the server?

Comment: @testfile yeah it worked just fine that's why I'm confused, maybe I don't have curl privilege with my script so it blocks my request or something like that?

Comment: so you tried to run it. It worked fine. But you're confused because it blocked your request? if it worked fine then it didnt block the request? In the screenshot you posted it made the request successfully so it didnt block the request?

Comment: @testfile The image did not appear after that output in the image. When I ran the command by hand(!) it did appear so I assumed something blocked my curl request in the script.

Comment: Appear as in opened the image in Photos or something?

Comment: @testfile appear as in it didn't download when using the script. it did appear when I wrote the command by hand in the command prompt.

Comment: Can you post the script?

Comment: @testfile Added it to the post

Comment: ok so what its doing is the curl command is going to the server. curl is executing and returning the output of curl. Which is the progress bar. The file is saved on the server and wont be transmitted back to the client. Also your `cd` command wont persist across calls. as in if you send `cd` and then curl the file, it wont save the file to where you `cd` to. Since the popen destroys the shell.

Comment: @testfile Solved it, you were right saying the popen destorys my cd command I ran both commands with '&' argument and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

CD command was overwritten by the curl command after it, in order to curl to a specified directory both cd and curl command need to be inputted at the same time with the '&' operator.

`cd C:\Users\User\Desktop && curl https://media.wired.co.uk/photos/607d91994d40fbb952b6ad64/4:3/w_2664,h_1998,c_limit/wired-meme-nft-brian.jpg --output yo.jpg`